# Unknown authentication scheme when liking post (LinkedIn API)

Tags: linkedin-api

Below goal is to like a post!

I get an error when trying to "Like" a post with the REST API (LinkedIn)
I have created an accesstoken with all scopes:

**scope=w_messages+rw_company_admin+rw_nus+r_emailaddress+r_basicprofile+rw_groups+r_fullprofile+r_network+r_contactinfo**

I can retreive comments from posts with the accesstoken which tell us that I have set it up correctly as a base.

However when I try to like a comment with the below code (just after in the same code where I have collected a comment), I receive this error:

**"unknown authentication scheme"**

I wonder why I can't like a post when I have set all scopes and I also have them checked in my application settings. Also notice that the postID is correct as I can retreive the comments for the post?

Thank you!

```
                        String accessToken = "MYLONGTOKEN"; //Just dummy example
                        String postID = "g-123456-S-123456789"; //Just dummy example
                        String requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/" + postID  + "/relation-to-viewer/is-liked&oauth2_access_token=" + accessToken;

                        RestSharp.RestClient rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
                        RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.PUT);
                        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

                        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;

                        restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
                        responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;


                        //unknown authentication scheme
                        MessageBox.Show(restResponse.Content.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which seems to work. The additional and replacement code is:

```
                //Comment this post
                requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/" + postID + "/comments?oauth2_access_token=" + accessToken;

                var comment = new
                {
                    text = "This is a comment!"
                };

                rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
                request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

                request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
                request.AddBody(comment);

                restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
                responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;

                MessageBox.Show(responseStatus.ToString() + "," + restResponse.Content.ToString());
```